How can I retain only the most complete information rows per group in a dplyr pipe statement?
I have an input dataset, which has partially redundant information (i.e. info) per group (i.e. ID) in several rows. Some rows for some groups are more complete (i.e. contain additional _detail info), while some groups also never have the full information. I would like to retain the most complete information lines per ID group and information type and discard the others. Also, I would like to be able to do this in a single dplyr pipe without intermediate variables.
Input example:
data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
           info = c("info1#info1_detail", "info1", "info3",
                    "info1",
                    "info1#info1_detail", "info1",
                    "info2#info2_detail", "info2"))

#>   ID               info
#> 1  1 info1#info1_detail
#> 2  1              info1
#> 3  1              info3
#> 4  2              info1
#> 5  3 info1#info1_detail
#> 6  3              info1
#> 7  3 info2#info2_detail
#> 8  3              info2

Desired output example:
data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
           info = c("info1#info1_detail",
                    "info3",
                    "info1",
                    "info1#info1_detail",
                    "info2#info2_detail"))

#>   ID               info
#> 1  1 info1#info1_detail
#> 2  1              info3
#> 3  2              info1
#> 4  3 info1#info1_detail
#> 5  3 info2#info2_detail


Please define "most complete information"

I think you need to provide more details. As Ronak asked, does the most complete row is the longest string (  slice_max(df, order_by = str_length(info), by = "ID"))?  The most occurence of # character? Why are you keeping  "info1#info1_detail" AND  "info2#info2_detail"  in ID =3?

Assuming infoX and infoXdetail are always separated by "#" you could use regular expression's positive look ahead to group by ID and the part of info with the least information, e.g.:
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                info = c("info1#info1_detail", "info1", "info3",
                         "info1",
                         "info1#info1_detail", "info1",
                         "info2#info2_detail", "info2"))
x %>% 
  arrange(ID, desc(info)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, stringr::str_extract(info, "(.*?)(?=\\#|$)")) %>% 
  summarize(info = first(info), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(ID, info)


The algorithm to decide what a most complete row is not clear to me. Here is an attempt based on the explanation in the post and the example shared.
library(dplyr)

most_complete_row <- function(str) {
  lgl <- grepl('_detail', str)
  if(any(lgl)) lgl else TRUE
}

df %>% filter(most_complete_row(info), .by = ID)

#  ID               info
#1  1 info1#info1_detail
#2  2              info1
#3  3 info1#info1_detail
#4  3 info2#info2_detail

Basically, this returns the rows that has "_detail" in it or else returns everything for a particular ID.

Note that the .by argument to filter() was introduced in dplyr 1.1.0.

Sorry I added an edge case to the example which changes the assumptions.
